# QAF - How to automate both WEB and MOBILE app using QAF

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, qaf

I am new to QAF. I need to automate both web and mobile app together. Let say, I have to do fund transfer using mobile native app and logout then immediately open desktop browser(Not Mobile browser) and open web application to verify the same transaction.

Since we need to configure both Appium driver and browser driver to achieve this scenario. How to handle this scenario using QAF framework.

Comment: Rafeek, I would like to connect with you on QAF. I am interested to see your implementation. Is it possible to send out an email to: vishwanathts@gmail.com ? So that we can connect later. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With QAF you can interact with multiple device/driver in single testcase. QAF has [support for Multiple Devices in one testcase](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/release_notes.html#ver-2111-release-notes). Driver can be for mobile or desktop browser. Provided capabilities for different drivers you can switch between drivers as required in test case. Assumed that you have [provided capabilities](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/setting_driver_capabilities.html) for `chrome` and `android` driver you can use more than one driver in same test as below:

```
QAFTestBase testbase = TestBaseProvider.instance().get();


testbase.setDriver("androidDriver");
//some steps with mobile


testbase.setDriver("chromeDriver");`
//some steps with chrome browser instance 1

testbase.setDriver("chrome2Driver");
//some steps with another chrome browser/driver`


testbase.setDriver("androidDriver");`
//switch to do something with mobile driver

testbase.setDriver("chromeDriver");`
//switch to do something with chrome browser instance 1

//tear down test case specific driver session that are no-more required
testbase.tearDown("chromeDriver");
testbase.tearDown("chrome2Driver");

testbase.setDriver("androidDriver");`
//switch back to mobile driver
```

Comment: Thank you!. Its working fine as expected.